# Matching dictionary values in a set of values using Python

Tags: python, mysql, twitter, sqlite

I am reading 1000 tweets from a Web file

```
wFD = urllib2.urlopen('http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/Twitter_2013_11_12.txt')
```

and then populating a table "TwTbl" with tweets(created_at, id, user_id, text, source). I have populated the table correctly. Now my task is to output the table values if the tweet ID does not end in "700". The code that I have for that is below:

```
IDs = c.execute("select distinct id from TwTbl where id like '%700'").fetchall()
set_keys = set(IDs)
f = open("dicttotxt2.txt", "w")
for tweet in tweets:
    str(tweet['id'])
    if str(tweet['id']) not in set_keys:
        for key in tweet:  
            try:
                print >>f, key, ": ", tweet[str(key)]
            except:
                pass
```

This code outputs to the text file, but it outputs everything. It is never matching the value of IDs on the set_keys. IDs has a list of 65 Ids. 
some of the values in ID are:

```
388453908898906100
388453908886351900
```

They are stored in the TwTbl as text fields.
Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you give us an example of type of values stored to IDs? Are they represented as strings or integers for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Would something without the database call work like this:

```
with open("dicttotxt2.txt", "w") as f:
    for tweet in tweets:
        if not str(tweet['id']).endswith('700'):
            for key in tweet:
                try: print >>f, key, ": ", tweet[str(key)]
                except: pass
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the input @Pi Marillion, but I HAVE to go through the list of values. This list has all the IDs that end in 700. I have spent so much time on it, but can not figure out how to fix it, as I am not very proficient in Python.

Comment: some of the values in ID are:
388453908881760260
388453908886351900
388453908898906100
In the table TwTbl they are stored as text fields.

Comment: @nasiajaffri I'm afraid I'm right out of ideas. Unless there is a type mismatch between `str(tweet['id'])` and `IDs` (E.g. if `IDs` is in int instead of a string), your code above should produce the desired effect. I hope another answer will elucidate it, though.